# What is the DateTimeStyles operator in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

When I add this code

```
DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal | DateTimeStyles.AllowInnerWhite
```

Intellisense shows the following message:

```
DateTimeStyles DateTimeStyles.operator |(DateTimeStyles left, DateTimeStyles right).
```

What does this operator do?

Comment: Where in intellisense you see this and when does intellisense show it?

Comment: You can refer MSDN for this

Comment: Why are there down-votes for this question? Given the limited information from the intellisense on Visual studio, there is very little that can be concluded or deduced on one's own for further reading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DateTimeStyles is a [Flags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447/what-does-the-flags-enum-attribute-mean-in-c) enumeration. The BITWISE OR operator `|` combines two flags.

See [Enum, Flags and bitwise operators](http://www.alanzucconi.com/2015/07/26/enum-flags-and-bitwise-operators/).

Answer (score 3):

`DateTimeStyles` isn't an operator - it's an enum, and all enums have the `|` operator. All it does is apply a bitwise `|` for the two values. It should only be used for flag-based enums. For example:

```
public enum AccessMode
{
    None = 0,
    Read = 1,
    Write = 2,
    Delete = 4
}
```

If you use:

```
AccessMode mode = AccessMode.Write | AccessMode.Delete;
```

then you'll have a value with an underlying integer value of 6.

Basically, it allows you to specify a single value representing multiple flags within the enum - so for you're example, you're saying "I want the result to be adjusted to UTC, and allow inner whitespace when parsing."

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Done.